# Having trouble to send email in live server using laravel 5.1

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, laravel-5.1

Hi I setup a contact form for my website with following configuration using Laravel framework

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.netregistry.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME= example@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM= example@domain.com
MAIL_NAME= name
```

the above config works fine in my localhost, however when I tried in live server it gives me error

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.netregistry.net [Connection refused #111]

I tried to fix it by changing mail server to smtp.gmail.com and even tried port 25, 465, 587 for encryption such as ssl, tls, startTLS none of them worked.

So I contacted hosting providers and asked for help and after 12 days of my struggle to get them address my issue finally come up with

> our cloud infrastructure does not allow external smtp connections from our hosting. This means that if you are sending emails from your website you will need to use localhost as the smtp host setting.

so now I tried to change my MAIL_HOST to localhost which gave me error

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.netregistry.net [Connection refused #0]

and now they were suggesting something wrong with my script. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is complete BS from your host. First thing, it's common for cloud systems to block OUTGOING SMTP, as it's a spam prevention measure, but your script is fine. Your host may be blocking everything but port 80, which means you can't connect to an SMTP host at all. You may be able to use localhost by not using SMTP at all, and use the builtin mailer(sendmail is common).

Change `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` to `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` to use php's built in mailer. This may solve your problem, if not, then you should seek other hosting arrangements.